# PhoneGap S4 overlay issues

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm developing a PhoneGap app with jQuery Mobile. the issue what am facing is white color box appears in the bottom of S4. it working fine on other devices. here I attached the screenshot. I tried out most of the possible ways, but I can't hide that Whitebox.
[image]

The following CSS code which is in use

```
.ui-dialog{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
    min-height: 100% !important;
    z-index:3000;
}
```

Comment: Add it on css .ui-dialog{overflow:hidden}.

Comment: @ Gamex overflow:hidden is used for only hide the scroll bar i think.can i know the reason why we use here this css code?

Comment: Basically it's a way of controlling layout and element "flow" http://www.w3schools.com/Css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_pos_overflow_hidden

Comment: @ Gamex it doesn't help..:(

Comment: IT's a button which going out side of the dailog. u can also fix the size of the content.